# ruby instance has no content assist (or autocomplete) with singleton pattern

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, singleton, content-assist

Below is a class with singleton pattern applied. But its instance has no content assist any more.

```
require 'singleton'
class Tst_case1
  include Singleton
  def sayHello
    puts "hello"
  end
end
case1 = Tst_case1.instance
case1. #there should be a popover listing the available methods, but no.
```

I test this on NetBeans 6.9.1 and Squish (an IDE based on eclipse), Both has not content assist. I think this is not IDE's issue, should be ruby's issue.

Is there any way to make the content assist work with the singleton pattern?
It's hard to write code with no content assist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't trust your IDE. If you write `case1.methods` in console, you get array like [:sayHello, ...]. All good.

Comment: Thanks very much, but I need to write code in IDE, so still need a work around to make content assist work.

Comment: "Content assist" is a feature of your IDE. Ruby doesn't "tell" your IDE what methods are available. Your IDE makes inferences about what methods are available by reading your Ruby code (and, perhaps, YARD or RDoc comments), which is just text. There's nothing Ruby can do to make your IDE behave differently. *You* may be able to give your IDE more information by writing YARD or RDoc comments, but that depends on your IDE. This is not a Ruby issue.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I am using ide from DLTK, do not know if it works with yard or Rdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out a workaround by not using the singleton lib. Write the singleton self.instanc method inside the class.